# How do I perform prediction algorithms on survey data?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, prediction

for example- I have a dataset like this
[image]

If I have an input like `"Son 19-30 Read the book No"` then how do I get the prediction of `online shopping` based on this? What kind of machine learning approach should I consider?

Comment: you can use support vector machines, knn, or perhaps just logistic regression. You have to do some data-preprocessing before giving it to a model. Like filling out missing values, dimensionality reduction, binning, converting text data to numerical data (such as one-hot encoding etc...). I can't explain all these topics to you. You have to figure out yourself.

Comment: Do you really only have those five rows of data? Or are those just five lines that you give us as an example, and you actually have more?

Comment: It was example.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's do it.
Firstly, we need preprocess the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing #for data preprocessing

df = ... #it's var for your table
```

We need to make gender binary (0 - male, 1 - female)

```
new_gender_columns = pd.get_dummies(df['Gender'])
```

Then add new_gender_columns to your DataFrame

```
df = df.join(new_gender_columns)
```

And we need to delete old object Gender column

```
df.drop('Gender', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But we need to make the same to Married column. For example, we could define function for all object columns or write previous code for Married.

```
def df_dummies(df, columns: list):
   for col in columns:
      new_dummies_columns = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
      df = df.join(new_dummies_columns)
      df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace = True)
   return df
```

Now, make list of object columns:

```
obj_cols = ['Gender', 'Married']
```

Run function:

```
df = df_dummies(df, obj_cols)
```

Then we have columns that we could process by label encoder. For example, age:

0-18  = label 0

19-30 = label 1

etc.

Let's make list of that columns:

```
labels_cols = ['Age', 'Leisure', 'Online Shopping']
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for col in labels_cols:
   le.fit(df[col])
   df[col] = le.transform(df[col])
```

Now, machine learning. Let's import random forest classifier. Because we need to predict classes ('yes' or 'no', 1 or 0).

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(df.iloc[:, :-1], df.iloc[:, -1])
```

Ok, model is fine, you are ready to test it. Have a safe journey, young padawan.

Comment: Random Forests usually give more robust results than Decision Trees, but I find that Decision Trees are more fun to play with for a beginner, because they can more easily be printed and understood. In other words, Random Forests have a more "black box" feel than Decision Trees.

Comment: I am getting this error after executing labels_cols = ['Age', 'Leisure', 'Online Shopping']
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for col in labels_cols:
   le.fit(df[col])
   df[col] = le.transform(df['col']). the error is Keyerror: col

Comment: Please, edit “col” to col

Answer (score 1):

You can use any classification algorithm for this problem but before that, you have to preprocess the data
For gender, you can use 0-1. 1 for son and 0 for girl
For Age, you can category onehotencoder 0-2 for different age groups.
For **Leisure** you have to use NLP technique to separate keywords in sentences, such as Games, Read Books, Internet, Music. These keywords can be used in onehotencoder.

After all that you can apply any classification algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important aspects of ML is data. The number of your dataset is very small.
On the other hand, it's a binary classification that has 2 classes. There is just one sample of class NO which mostly makes your model tend to predict Yes.

So, I recommend you to find more data first, then for predicting you can use Decision Trees, Support Vector Machines, and Logistic Regressions.

Comment: Yeah, with just those five lines of data, a Decision Tree would probably conclude either "If it's a girl, it doesn't shop online; if it's a boy, it shops online" or "If it reads the book, it doesn't shop online; if it doesn't read the book, it shops online".